# How to call a setter method from html file in Tapestry3

Tags: java, html, tapestry

Hi i am using Tapestry3 framework. Here i can simply call a getter method by doing `ognl:myMethod`. It will simply invoke `getMyMethod().` But how will call `setMyMethod`..Is there any way. Or is it possible to to call a java method from html page with a parameter.

or more precisely  ,,just how to set a value from html page to java page in Tapestry3

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the following in Tapestry 5. Not sure about 3

Im not sure about a direct way. And What I do is invoking a action link with some parameter. So the method can be

```
object onActionFromFoo(String value){
//TODO
return null;
}
```